# Trying to call different macro if cell is blank or not blank

Tags: excel, vba

Having trouble getting anything to work right today. I am trying to call (macro 1) if a cell is blank call (macro 2) if the same cell is not blank.

Comment: please show the `If` block you tried.

Comment: `If IsEmpty(myRange.Value) Then...Macro1...Else...Macro2...End If`.

Comment: And does it through an error or always run one macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code, its hard to debug, so I wrote this out for you really quick to provide you with an example which I believe would answer your question in full.

```
    Sub ChkEmpty()

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
    Call Macro1
Else
    Call Macro2
End If

End Sub

Sub Macro1()

ActiveCell.Value = "Macro1"

End Sub

Sub Macro2()

ActiveCell.Value = "Macro2"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this pointed out my error. For some reason it didn't dawn on me I wasn't calling out the active cell. It works now. Normally would've caught that. Thanks for your help, I will now go sit in my corner.